Why NOAA layers appear to be incorrect
I had previously built a Leaflet map that pulled past precipitation data (24, 48, and 72 hours) from the NOAA nowCOAST site, however, the site was decommissioned. I used a previous StackExchange post to built the Leaflet map here: Adding weather radar data to leaflet from website
The goal of my map was to match the map shown at this website:
https://www.iweathernet.com/total-rainfall-map-24-hours-to-72-hours
which looks like this:

To reiterate, the leaflet map and the map at this website had matched previously. After the decommission of nowCOAST, I inspected the new data source for the site at it revealed that it is pulling data from a NOAA mapserver: https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/rest/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer

The problem arises when I try to use the same data pull to recreate the leaflet map. I used R, like so:
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)

tdir=tempdir()
stateurl = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip"
if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp",sep=""))==F){
  download.file(stateurl, destfile = file.path(tdir, "States.zip"))
  unzip(file.path(tdir,"States.zip"),exdir=tdir)}
NYS = read_sf(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp",sep="")) %>%
  filter(NAME=="New York") %>%
  st_transform(.,crs=32618)
USA = read_sf(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp",sep="")) %>%
  filter(!c(GEOID%in%c("72","02","60","78","15","69","66"))) %>%
  st_union()


url = "https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer/WMSServer?"
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines(data=USA,
               color = "red",
               stroke = TRUE,
               weight=3,
               group = "USA") %>%
  addWMSTiles(url,
              layers="25",
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png",
                                       transparent = TRUE,
                                       opacity=.7),
              group = "24-Hr Accumulation")


Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.0.2
Clearly, the map created by pulling from the data source does not match the website.

Have you tried different layer numbers? For me, layer 253 looks like the 1h accumulation map. Check with the WMS capabilties metadata https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer/WMSServer?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities

Wow, that worked. I found the correct layer numbers there. Just curious, why does it not match up with the layer numbers here? https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/raster/rest/services/obs/rfc_qpe/MapServer

Those layer numbers are MapServer API layers, you're using a WMS server API in your URL. Assuming this is the WMS add-on to MapServer, its controlled by its own configuration file so it has a potentially different layer list available.

@Spacedman I think this should go into an answer. Weather data is widely used and answer might help somebody with the same/similar problem.
